# Unit Test Firestore CallbackFlow

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I wrote the following code to test Firestore data reading with coroutines' `runTest` function:

```
@Test
fun `callbackFlow should read trip`() =
    runTest {
        log("test started")
        var result: DocumentSnapshot? = null

        val flow = callbackFlow {
            log("callbackFlow started")
            val listener = firestore
                .collection("/collection")
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                    e?.let {
                        log("error")
                        close()
                    }

                    snapshot?.let {
                        log("success")
                        trySend(snapshot.documents[0])
                    }
                }
            log("just before awaitClose")
            awaitClose {
                listener.remove()
                log("callbackFlow closed")
            }
        }

        val collectJob = launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
            log("collect started")
            result = flow.first()
            log("item collected")
        }

        log("join started")
        collectJob.join()
        log("join terminated")

        log("assertion started")
        assertThat(result).isNotNull()
        log("assertion terminated")
        log("test terminated")
    }

private fun TestScope.log(msg: String) {
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name}, ${coroutineContext[Job]} $currentTime: $msg")
}
```

I tried to play with `testDispatcher`s in many places, but nothing seems to work. When I tested with `QuerySnapshot`'s `get()` function, everything works fine. Every time I run the test, it gives me the following output:

```
SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#4, TestScope[test started] 0: test started
SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#5, TestScope[test started] 0: collect started
SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#6, TestScope[test started] 0: callbackFlow started
SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#6, TestScope[test started] 0: just before awaitClose
SDK 29 Main Thread @coroutine#4, TestScope[test started] 0: join started

After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: ["coroutine#5":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@54fb9234]
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: ["coroutine#5":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@54fb9234]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$3$3.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:304)
    (Coroutine boundary)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(TestBuilders.kt:288)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt$createTestResult$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
    Suppressed: org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment$UnExecutedRunnablesException: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle() call.
Caused by: kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: ["coroutine#5":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@54fb9234]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$3$3.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:304)
    at app//kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:12)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:166)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:154)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:147)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.mersal.rider.home.HomeViewModelTripTest.callbackFlow should read trip(HomeViewModelTripTest.kt:117)
    at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.12/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.12/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at app//org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at app//org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:591)
    at app//org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:274)
    at app//org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:88)
    at java.base@11.0.12/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base@11.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base@11.0.12/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

How can I pass the test?